# Manipulating C++ member variables that begin with $ in GDB

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, gdb

I'm working with a C++ code base with a very peculiar coding style, including prefixing member variables in classes with '$'.  For anyone who's never come across this before, it's not formally part of C++ standards, but [lurks around for backwards compatibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html#Dollar-Signs).

As an example of what I'm talking about:

```
#include <iostream>

class T { public: int $x; int y; };

int main()
{
  T *t = new T();
  t->$x = t->y = 42;
  std::cout << "t->$x = " << t->$x << std::endl;
  delete t;
  return 0;
}
```

This introduces a problem in GDB.  GDB normally uses $ prefixed variables as a magic convenience variable (such as referring to previous values).  Fire up GDB, set a breakpoint at the cout statement, and try to print `t->$x`.

`p t` runs fine.  `p *t` runs fine.  `p t->y` runs fine.  `p t->$x` returns a syntax error, presumably expecting the $ to refer to a convenience variable.

Ideally, I'd strip the $s out entirely and spend the rest of my days hunting down whoever thought that was a good idea (especially for a modern codebase).  That's not realistic, but I still need to be able to use GDB for debugging.

I'm hoping there's a magic escape character, but nothing I've searched for or tried has worked.

Examples:

- `p this->'\044descriptor'`
- `p this->'$descriptor'`
- `p this->'$'descriptor`
- `p this->\$descriptor`
- `p this->\\$descriptor`
- `p this->'\$descriptor'`
- `p this->'\\044descriptor'`
- `p this->$$descriptor`
- `p this->'$$descriptor'`

and so on.

In this particular case, I can run the getter function (`p this->getDescriptor()`).  An uglier workaround is to print the entire class contents (`p *this`).  I'm not sure I can rely on both of those indefinitely; some of the classes are fairly large, and most member variables don't have getters.

This could potentially be classified as a bug in GDB, depending on whether it's a good idea to rip up input to support this.  However, even if it was fixed, I'm stuck on GDB 7.2 for the given architecture/build environment.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: `python import gdb; print (gdb.parse_and_eval("t")['$x'])` as suggested in the comment works if you have python builtin (which I don't have, unfortunately).

Comment: backwards compability is evil, isnt it?

Comment: Is the code base actively maintained on a repository like github?  Could this be cleaned up in the source code, maybe updated on the repository, or could you fork it and clean it up there?  If you're stuck with GDB tripping over this, that may be your best option.... though count the cost in hours to do so.

Comment: Have you tried using `$$` to escape it?

Comment: It's a proprietary codebase, and one recently introduced to my company by way of acquisition.  I'm trying to make my case that's it's worth refactoring that quirk out.  I'm using the dual argument of It's Worth Refactoring That Quirk Out and Srsly This Code Is Like Five Years Old... Just Why?

Also, $$ doesn't work either; I'll add that to the list.

Comment: 2 more things that don't work: #define dollar(x) $##x (gdb) p this->dollar(x) with -g3 or the macro define equivalent

Comment: Try `(gdb) python import gdb; print (gdb.parse_and_eval("t")['$x'])`.

Comment: If it were possible to use a UCN, it would be '\u0024x', not '\044x'. But UCNs don't work either :(

Comment: Gdb 7.2 did support python scripting, so if your gdb 7.2 doesn't have it, I'd guess that either your system doesn't have the necessary python shared library installed, or your gdb was specially compiled with python disabled. To resolve your question, you may need to install python or may need to recompile gdb (either with python support enabled or with a change, if we can find one, to the C expression parser to allow member names that begin with $). Are any of those things possible in your environment?

Answer (score 1):

If you got the gdb version with python extensions, maybe the "explore" feature will help.

See https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Data.html#Data

```
  (gdb) explore cs
     The value of `cs' is a struct/class of type `struct ComplexStruct' with
     the following fields:

       ss_p = 
        arr = 

     Enter the field number of choice:
```

Since you don't need the variable name, you should be able to step around the '$' issue.